# Move many S3 buckets to Glacier

Tags: amazon-s3, archiving, amazon-glacier

We have a ton of *S3 buckets* and are in the process of cleaning things up. We identified *Glacier* as a good way to archive their data. The plan is to store the content of those buckets and then remove them.
It would be a one-shot operation, we don't need something automated.

I know that:

- a bucket name may not be available anymore if one day we want to restore it
- there's an indexing overhead of about 40kb per file which makes it a not so cost-efficient solution for small files and better to use an *Infrequent access* storage class or to zip the content

I gave it a try and created a vault. But I couldn't run the **aws glacier** command. I get some SSL error which is apparently related to a *Python* library, wether I run it on my *Mac* or from some dedicated container.

Also, it seems that it's a pain to use the *Glacier API* directly (and to keep the right file information), and that it's simpler to use it via a dedicated bucket.

What about that? Is there something to  do what I want in *AWS*? Or any advice to do it in a not too fastidious way? What tool would you recommend?

Comment: If you wish to resolve your `aws glacier` app problem, please raise it as a separate question.

Comment: No need. The issue is on Github: https://github.com/uskudnik/amazon-glacier-cmd-interface/issues/180 but I found a solution without calling `aws glacer` directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a *S3* archiving bucket did the job.
Here is how I proceeded:

First, I created a *S3 bucket* called **mycompany-archive**, with a lifecycle rule that turns the *Storage class* into *Glacier* 1 day after the file creation.

Then, (with the **aws** tool installed on my Mac) I ran the following **aws** command to obtain the buckets list: `aws s3 ls`

I then pasted the output into an editor that can do *regexp* relacements, and I did the following one:

Replace `^\S*\s\S*\s(.*)$` by `aws s3 cp --recursive s3://$1 s3://mycompany-archive/$1 && \`

It gave me a big command, from which I removed the trailing `&& \` at the end, and the lines corresponding the buckets I didn't want to copy (mainly **mycompany-archive** had to be removed from there), and I had what I needed to do the transfers.

That command could be executed directly, but I prefer to run such commands using the **screen** util, to make sure the process wouldn't stop if I close my session by accident.
To launch it, I ran `screen`, launched the command, and then pressed *CTRL+A* then *D* to detach it. I can then come back to it by running `screen -r`.

Finally, under *MacOS*, I ran `cafeinate` to make sure the computer wouldn't sleep before it's over. To run it, issued `ps|grep aws` to locate the *process id* of the command. And then `caffeinate -w 31299` (the process id) to ensure my *Mac* wouldn't allow sleep before the process is done.

It did the job (well, it's still running), I have now a bucket containing a folder for each archived bucket. Next step will be to remove the undesired *S3 buckets*.
Of course this way of doing could be improved in many ways, mainly by turning everything into a fault-tolerant replayable script. In this case, I have to be pragmatic and thinking about how to improve it would take far more time for almost no gain.

Answer (score 6):

Whoa, so many questions!

There are two ways to use Amazon Glacier:

- **Create a [Lifecycle Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-lifecycle.html)** on an Amazon S3 bucket to archive data to Glacier. The objects will still *appear* to be in S3, including their security, size, metadata, etc. However, their contents are stored in Glacier. Data stored in Glacier via this method must be restored back to S3 to access the contents.
- **Send data directly to Amazon Glacier** via the AWS API. Data sent this way must be restored via the API.

Amazon Glacier charges for storage volumes, plus per request. It is less-efficient to store many, small files in Glacier. Instead, it is recommended to create *archives* (eg zip files) that make fewer, larger files. This can make it harder to retrieve specific files.

If you are going to use Glacier directly, it is *much* easier to use a utility, such as [Cloudberry Backup](https://www.cloudberrylab.com/backup/windows.aspx), however these utilities are designed to backup from a computer to Glacier. They probably won't backup S3 to Glacier.

**If data is already in Amazon S3, the simplest option is to create a lifecycle policy.** You can then use the S3 management console and standard S3 tools to access and restore the data.

Comment: Ok, using an archive S3 bucket indeed seems to be simplest way. I managed to do something with it, I'm gonna post an answer bout that.